# How to create conditional statement for empty int input (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x

What would be the proper way of creating a conditional statement that will print to the user 'Error: This field has not been filled out' if the user does not enter an integer value.

for example for this statement:

```
user_Input = input('Enter a string: ')
if not user_Input:
  print('Error: This field has not been filled out')
else:
  print(user_Input)
```

the program will print ('Error: This field has not been filled out') is the user does not enter a value, but if we do the same for an integer. Let's say:

```
user_Input = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
if not user_Input:
  print('Error: This field has not been filled out')
else:
  print(user_Input)
```

It will yield a value error.

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

How could I get the second statement to have the same output as the first statement without having a value error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int("")` isn't valid, so you need to validate the input string *before* you try to parse it as an integer.

```
user_Input = input('Enter a string: ')
if not user_Input:
  print('Error: This field has not been filled out')
else:
  value = int(user_Input)
  print(value)
```

This only filters the empty string; the user could still provide an invalid string. Instead of trying to prevent the `ValueError`, just catch it. Try something like

```
while True:
    user_input = input('Enter a int: ')
    try:
        value = int(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid integer '%s', try again" % (user_input,))
    else:
        break
```